# How to compute marginals in Sum-Product Networks?

Tags: inference, graphical-model, marginal-distribution

This should be fairly easy, but for some reason i'm having hard time getting it to work and I've spent a long time trying to figure it out myself.

In the last paragraph of page 4 of the original [Sum-Product Networks paper](http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~pedrod/papers/uai11a.pdf) the authors described how to compute the posterior marginals of sum nodes, i.e $$P(Y_k = i | e) \propto w_{k,i} \frac{\partial S}{\partial S_K}\,,$$ where $Y_k$ is a sum node and $i$ is an edge to one of its child nodes.

Let's assume that I've a very simple network like this one:

[image: Simple SPN]

and I want to compute the marginal of the sum node given an evidence (which can be either: $e=\text{x}$ or $e=\text{not_x}$). The partial derivative of the sum node should be $1$ because it's the root:

$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial S_{sum}} = 1$$
then the marginals should be:
$$P(sum = 1 | e) \propto w_{sum,w_1} $$
$$P(sum = 2 | e) \propto w_{sum,w_2} $$
(where 1 and 2 referees to the edges)

My problem is that these two equations don't depend on the evidence and they give the same results regardless of what the evidence is. I tried with different structures and I keep getting the same results.

This is important because Sum nodes are seen as hidden variables in Sum-Product Networks and computing their posterior marginals is an important step in order to implement the Expectation-Maximization learning algorithm.

How can I correctly compute the posterior marginal of the sum nodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a typo in the formula in the paper.  It should read $P(Y_k=i | e) \propto  w_{k,i} \frac{\partial S}{\partial S_k} N_i$, where $N_i$ is the value of child $i$.

So in your example, you would get $P(sum=1|e)\propto w_1 x$.  You can confirm this by computing $$P(sum=1|e) = \frac{P(sum=1,e)}{P(e)} = \frac{w_1x}{w_1x+w_2\bar{x}} \propto w_1x$$